# How to fix (29,20): error CS1519: Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't compile it, no matter what I do

I have tried every possible changing
Help me to make it compile, for me the code is perfect but still it isn't working

```
 [System.Serializable]
public class UnderWaterParameters {
    [Header("The following parameters apply for underwater only!")]
    [Space(5)]
    public float fogDensity = 0.1f;
    public Color fogColor;
#if UNITY_POST_PROCESSING_STACK_V1 && AQUAS_PRESENT
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Post Processing Profiles (Must NOT be empty!)")]
    [Space(5)]
    public PostProcessingProfile underwaterProfile;
    public PostProcessingProfile defaultProfile;
#endif

#if UNITY_POST_PROCESSING_STACK_V2 && AQUAS_PRESENT
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Post Processing Profiles (Must NOT be empty!)")]
    [Space(5)]
    public PostProcessingProfile underwaterProfile;
    public PostProcessingProfile defaultProfile;
#endif
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the error tells you _where_ it is. At first glance I'd say: you have three unnecessary attributes at the end of the class (one of them even twice). Attributes have to be applied to members, but there only follows an unexpected `}`

Comment: Well....... the ending } is inside an #if, so if thats not true theres no closing brace, but there doesnt seem to be another, as theres 2 starting ones.

Comment: It would be great if you could post enough code that we can see the ending curly braces. Also, you have an ending curly brace inside an `#if` which means that it may or may not be included in the actual code. If you have curly braces inside precompiler statements like that, it's good practice to make sure that both the starting and ending curly braces are inside `#if` statements with the same expression so they'll be included or excluded together.

Comment: An attribute (e.g. `[Space(5)]`) must allways preceed a member, class or any other symbol. So to which of them should the last three lines apply?

Comment: Don´t paste links to your code. In particular that links seems suspicious for my firewall. Instead provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Space(5)]
    [Header("Post Processing Profiles (Must NOT be empty!)")]
    [Space(5)]
    public PostProcessingProfile underwaterProfile;
    public PostProcessingProfile defaultProfile; it was like this earlier but it was giving an error of using underwaterProfile and defaultProfile twice so i removed them

Comment: @Tayyab Perhaps you want `#elseif` rather than a second `#if`? Either way, if only the attributes change, it might make more sense to only put the attributes in conditional compilation blocks.

Comment: I have tried `#elseif` it doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question with the actual code, not the comments. Anyway: as I already mentioned your last four lines make no sense, the attributes can´t stand allonw. I assume you want different attributes based on the unity-version. So you should only wrap the attribute-lines **above** `underwaterProfile` into `#if elseif`-stamentns.

Comment: And what error do you get now?

Comment: @HimBromBeere with this code i get this error **Assets\AQUAS\Scripts\AQUAS_LensEffects.cs(93,22): error CS0102: The type 'AQUAS_LensEffects' already contains a definition for 'postProcessing'** and this **Assets\Gaia\Scripts\Attributes\PreviewTextureAttribute.cs(17,16): warning CS0618: 'WWW' is obsolete: 'Use UnityWebRequest, a fully featured replacement which is more efficient and has additional features'**

Comment: Then I suppose both of your conditions apply. You should use an `#if elif` as written in my answer.

Comment: actually that error is fixed now but so many other errors have appeared

Answer (score 2):

An `Attribute` (that´s what you define by using `[...]`) gives **metadata** about a class or a class-member. In other words it can´t stand allone, it allways has to preceed some symbol. That´s why this does not compile:

```
#if UNITY_POST_PROCESSING_STACK_V2 && AQUAS_PRESENT
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Post Processing Profiles (Must NOT be empty!)")]
    [Space(5)] } <-- attribute must preceed a member or class
#endif
```

It seems to me all you want is different attributes based on which of the two conditions apply, so you should **wrap only those lines into `#if #elif` which should be different, not those that are common**.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UnderWaterParameters {
    [Header("The following parameters apply for underwater only!")]
    [Space(5)]
    public float fogDensity = 0.1f;
    public Color fogColor;
#if UNITY_POST_PROCESSING_STACK_V1 && AQUAS_PRESENT
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Post Processing Profiles (Must NOT be empty!)")]
    [Space(5)]
#elif UNITY_POST_PROCESSING_STACK_V2 && AQUAS_PRESENT
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Post Processing Profiles (Must NOT be empty!)")]
    [Space(5)] }
#endif
    public PostProcessingProfile underwaterProfile;
    public PostProcessingProfile defaultProfile;
}
```

Of course the above doesn´t make much sense, as in both cases the exact same attributes are applied. But that seems another question to me.

See also the docs from MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-elif